# Conditional rendering parts of form based on selected option

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I am pretty new in react and im currently working on creating a react component that allows user to enter feedback. I want to create a feedback form that has 2 types of feedback. The user should be able to select between type 1 and type 2 and based on his option to render different form fields.

This is my code for now:

```
    import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'

function Feedback() {

return( 
    <form id="live_form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
            Feedback Type
            </label>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option selected>Choose feedback type</option>
                <option value="1">One</option>
                <option value="2">Two</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
            Enter feedback for option 1
            </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">
            Enter feedback for option
            </label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </form>            
)

}

export default Feedback;
```

What i want is when the option 1 is selected to display only the first textarea and when the option 2 is selected to display only the second textarea. Can someone explain how can i check whick option is selected in order to render the rest of the form based on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a state variable to store the selected option and then, based on this value, to render the equivalent parts

```
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);

    <select
      class="form-select"
      onChange={(e) => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}
    >
```

and

```
  {selectedOption === "1" && (
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Enter feedback for option 1</label>
      <textarea
        class="form-control"
        id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
        rows="3"
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  )}
```

Check

[this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ishizaka-6omeq)

Comment: I think it work perfectly for what i need. Thanks for the answear. If i have another question i'll come back with a comment.